# Android Wheelview Repeating Values

Tags: android

I have a wheelview with this set of adapter

```
NumericWheelAdapter minAdapter = new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 00, 30);
```

the problem was, after counting to 9 it display "1" again. like this

5
6
7
8
9
1
1
1

it should be like this 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

I think view Holder is needed to fix this problem. 
Can anyone know how to implement view holder in wheel view adapter?
any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting `NumericWheelAdapter` from? [This?](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/trunk/wheel/src/kankan/wheel/widget/NumericWheelAdapter.java?r=12) Or is it your own class?

Comment: I get it from here  http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

Comment: do you have a NumericWheelAdapter that don't repeat the values?

Comment: See, looking at the code, it appears to generate the list of numbers fine. I think the "0", "1", and "2" of "10", "11", and "12" are getting cut off because the wheel is not wide enough.

Comment: yes! its just cut off by the width thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output you're *seeing*, the `0`, `1`, and `2` of the `10`, `11`, and `12` elements are just being cut off due to the width. Just alter the `WheelView`'s width to adapt to the wider elements.

Comment: Sir do you know how to view images using wheelview?

Comment: No, I don't, though I suspect you'd have to implement your own adapter for that. You may want to start a new question for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I usually build the new library based on the WheelView Yuri Kanivets designed.
This is my works , Hope you will like.
https://code.google.com/p/wheel-controllers/

Answer (score 0):

```
new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 00, 30,"%02d");
```

That did the trick for me, that also made it possible to make much larger numbers in a single scroll wheel.